# how to Synchronize date & time between PC and mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i have WebService in the PC

and i get date & time in `dd/mm/yyyy`  and on another PC in `mm/dd/yyyy`

i have any Windows-CE mobile that connect to this PC

how to Synchronize date & time between PC and mobile ?

(i need that the PC date & time will be in the monile)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web service should expose the date and time in a standard format (e.g. ISO-8601). If your web method is declared to return a `DateTime`, this should happen automatically - the situation you've described should only occur if you're explicitly doing something like:

```
return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("d");
```

... don't do that, basically.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date of your Smartphone to ISO format (i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd`) then send it to your PC and convert it there from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `mm/dd/yyyy`